# Textbox event binding and textbox value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have my Textbox as:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control textbox" data-bind="value: nameValue, , event: { 'keyup': checkIfTextBoxEmpty }" />
```

As you can see above I am using keyup event on my textbox.

And the event in knockout is as below:

```
   self.checkIfTextBoxEmpty = function (data, event) {
       //To check if textbox is empty
       if(data.nameValue() == '')
        {
           //hide a span tag 
        }
    };
```

When the user enters no value and press the button on my page I already have validator wired up to this textbox which shows the error "Field is required".

If they enter invalid value in the textbox I check that in my button click and show that as error in a span which is below the textbox.

The issue comes when the user enters invalid value and press button it shows the invalid value error and they when they delete the value entered in the textbox it shows both the required field error as well as the invalid value error.

So I tied up "keyup" event to the textbox. Here I want to check if the value is empty I would hide the span tag so that it just shows required field error.

But in my keyup event data.nameValue() is always undefined so I am not able to check the value they entered.

Is there anything else that needs to be done here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer mentioned above by Tomalak is the correct way to approach.

For your answer regarding how to use an event, you can try out the following code.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control textbox" data-bind="value: nameValue, 
 valueUpdate: 'value' , event: { 'keyup': checkIfTextBoxEmpty }" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see above I am using keyup event on my textbox.

You shouldn't. You shouldn't use any event at all. Use [the `textInput` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html) and a computed value.

```js
function VM() {
  var self = this;

  self.nameValue = ko.observable('');
  
  self.nameIsEmpty = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.nameValue() == '';
  });
};

var vm = new VM();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: nameValue">

<span data-bind="visible: nameIsEmpty">Field is required</span>
```

In the longer run you should learn the [Knockout-Validation plugin](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) instead of rolling your own validation code.

Comment: Thanks I will look into and make my changes according to your code above and also look into ko validations. Since I am new to KO just for my knowledge I wanted to know, since we define a two way binding on the textbox. Why on keyup event data.nameValue() comes to be undefined. Is there someother event that needs to be tied up to get the textbox value. Because when I debug I can see the event being hit, its just the value being empty. Thanks

Comment: Any inputs to my question about.?

Comment: What's with the event? Why do you care?